# Calculating and summing time between subsequent SQL entries

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table containing entries with a UNIX timestamp for when a machine entered a state. Each time the machine changes state, it creates another entry with the new state and timestamp. Here is a sample of the data:

```
 State    Time
     1    1559159686041
     2    1559159636838
     3    1559159420521
     1    1559159420521
     2    1559159420521
     1    1559159420521
```

I need to calculate how long the total time the machine was in each state over a 24 hour period.

How can I write a query that will calculate the time between each entry and sum the times by state type?

I would like the final result to look like:

```
 State    TotalTime
     1    23153425
     2    344
     3    4534
```

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

Comment: What would the desired result look like? While pondering that, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query